# How to use layout weight when you want to toggle one of 2 visible views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout that will have a cancel button and a progress bar, where the progress bar is 70% and the cancel button is 30%, like so:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >

 <ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/uploadProgressBar"
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight=".7"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     />
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/uploadCancelButton"
     style="@style/TitleBarButton"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight=".3"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/cancel_btn"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

      />

 </LinearLayout>
```

This works fine, however I realized that actually I either want to show the progress bar or a text view, where the text view could be a small status message (if say the upload failed).

I tried putting a TextView in the the above LinearLayout and having its visibility set to "gone" by default and with the weight set the same as the progress bar. In the code I would only set either the progress bar to visible or the text view, and the other I would set to gone. However the android system appeared to contribute the invisible items weight to the total. I even tried using android:weightSum="1.0" in the LinearLayout xml attributes but that then my button was no longer visible as even though the text was gone, it took space.

Comment: Paul beat me to an answer and what he proposes will do what you're after. Essentially there is nothing wrong with using an inner layout class such as a `ViewFlipper` or a `FrameLayout` as you proposed in which you would then contain the `View`s that swap in and out of sight. Also you might want to be clearer in your wording, as saying "the weights messed everything up" doesn't convey any meaning and from the last paragraph I cannot really grasp what it is you don't like about using an inner container.

Comment: @Trevor, I updated the description. I also removed the last part as it was an obvious brainfart and was thinking I would need to add the inner views in java instead of just putting them in the xml directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) is what you are looking for.

It is very simple to use. You put the views you want to toggle inside the ViewFlipper exactly the same way like you would place them within a Layout inside XML. Then from code you call `setDisplayedChild()` on the `ViewFlipper` object containing your views. The parameter of this method is the index of the view that you want to be shown.